# How specific does a "tools" recommendation question have to be to become constructive?

Tags: discussion

I'm a bit concerned about the question [What are some good tools one can use for creating and maintaining an online CV?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1746/what-are-some-good-tools-one-can-use-for-creating-and-maintaining-an-online-cv) and the creation of the [tools](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) tag. It's very easy for these to become list questions and answers are often based around personal preference rather than some software/ect actually being outright superior.

Some sites have allowed this questions as long as they are asking for tools for **a very specific and well defined purpose**, meaning that Product B really is superior to Product A for this particular task because of X feature which helps you Y. I do *not* want to open the door for "my favorite word processor is Pages".

Can we work with these questions at all? If so, what makes a "good" one and what makes them Not Constructive?

Answer (score 7):

I **am** in favor of soliciting tool information specifically to help solve **a very specific and well-defined purpose**, as you said.  Here I'm thinking about questions that come up on [Project Management SE](http://pm.stackexchange.com) -- it has its fair share of oft-closed polling questions, e.g. "What are some good PM tools you all use?" -- but also perfectly fine questions, such as ["What Lightweight/Project Management or Bug Tracker Software Can I Use to Manage Exceptions, Milestones, and Old Bugs?"](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/4947/what-lightweight-project-management-or-bug-tracker-software-can-i-use-to-manage)

However, I am **not** in favor of tool solicitations for general purposes because they are little more than a poll/the same information could be found via Google and thus are Not Constructive.

Using  [What are some good tools one can use for creating and maintaining an online CV?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1746/what-are-some-good-tools-one-can-use-for-creating-and-maintaining-an-online-cv) as an example, I would close this as Not Constructive.  The title, and repeated as the last question, is specifically polling.  Now, the lead-in itself doesn't actually match the title/the question, because it's about how applicant tracking systems are a pain in the butt. That is true, but the question asked doesn't solve that problem.

If this were a question about how to store one's personal information so as to deal with applicant tracking systems when encountered, that would be a constructive question (even though you can't do that with ATSes, I could certainly explain why).  But it's not that question.

Comment: This sounds reasonable, I made a similar point on UX earlier http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/a/989/7627 . For the record I also consider the current wording of the CV question Not Constructive.